# iterating through and changing nodes in singly linked list

Tags: javascript, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The problem is I don't understand why this code works.  It works, but I just can't wrap my mind around it.  Here's a function that deletes a node from a singly linked list.  I feel like it shouldn't work because it's not actually changing any of the elements in the list, I'm just changing the value of a variable I have set equal to something in the list.  In other words, when I create a "runner" variable to iterate through the list, why are the changes I make to "runner" actually changing the list itself.  Analogously, if I do

```
var x = 1
var y = x
y = 2
```

Obviously, x is still going to equal 1.  Why isn't the same true for my Linked List "runner".  In the deleteNode function below, why does changing the runner.next value actually change anything in the node or list that exists outside of the function?

```
function deleteNode(head, position) {
    var runner = head
    var counter = 0
    while (runner) {
        if (counter == position - 1) {
            runner.next = runner.next.next
            return head;
        }
        runner = runner.next
        counter++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because runner is an object, and so the runner variable is a reference to that object.

for example

```
const x = {a:1}
const y = x;
x.a = 3
console.log(y.a) // this will print 3 also
```

Comment: typo `const x = {a:1]`

Comment: Why then does the value of "head" not change when I do runner=runner.next?  If runner is referencing head, shouldn't the head reference change when I change runner?